# Firebase 9 - how to chain 'addDoc' or similar to a 'collection'?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Previously in Firebase you could add a document like this:

```
const myNewDoc = await db.collection('some-collection-name').add({ //Document details here... });
```

With the introduction of Firebase 9 this no longer works.

Instead of `.add` I think I am supposed to use an imported `.addDoc` method.

But it seems I cannot chain `.addDoc` onto `.collection`.

If I try to do something like this:

```
const myNewDoc = await db.collection('some-collection-name').addDoc({ //Document details here... });
```

TypeScript throws this error:

```
Property 'addDoc' does not exist on type 'CollectionReference<DocumentData>'.ts(2339)
```

I *could* create something more verbose like this:

```
const someCol = collection(db, "some-collection-name");
const newDoc = await addDoc(someCol, {
    //Document details here...
});
```

But I would rather "chain" it like before.

Is that possible? How would it be done?

And should I even be using `.addDoc`? Or something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `addDoc()` is a top level function in Modular SDK. Try refactoring your code like this:

```
import { collection, addDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 

const newDoc = await addDoc(collection(db, "some-collection-name"), {
  // Document Data
});
console.log("Document written with ID: ", newDoc.id);
```

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document) has examples of both name-spaced and the new syntax.

---

If you are using `compat` version to use older syntax then you would have to use `add()` itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Firestore, collection, collectionData, addDoc } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

firestore: Firestore = inject(Firestore);

addDoc(collection( this.firestore, 'some-collection-name'),Document details here
)
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.